Prove that $\dim(S_n)=n^2-n+1$
This question came up in my math exam today:

Let $S_n$ be the set that contains all square matrices of order $n$ such that the sum of all the elements in any row of the matrix is equal to a constant. For example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  \\
 3&0 
\end{bmatrix}$ belongs to $S_2$ since the sum of the elements in the first row ($1+2=3$) is equal to the sum of elements in the second row ($3+0=3$).
Prove that $\dim(S_n)=n^2-n+1$

I truly have no idea were to start. In previews items the problem asked to find a base for $S_2$ and to prove that $S_n$ is a subspace (Close under addition and scalar multiplication). I don´t know how this findings can help in solving the problem.
PD: It should be simple since the item was worth 1.5 points of 20 in the exam it came up.

$S^n$ is an $n^2$ dimensional space. Then this subspace defines $n-1$ restrictions on the space by setting the sum of each of rows equal to the sum of the first (but not $n$ because the sum of the first row is not specified). The dimension of a subspace is always the dimension of the whole space minus the number of restrictions, which is $n^2-(n-1)$

What is a restriction of a subspace? How do you know $S_n$ is an $n^2$ dimensional space? We didn´t saw that concepts in class, including the "The dimension of a subspace is always the dimension of the whole space minus the number of restrictions..." part. Is there any other way to reach $n^2-n+1$?

I misspoke, I meant to say that the space of square matrices is an $n^2$ dimensional space.

I found a basis for $S_2$, not for $S_n$. The prevews item asked for a basis for $S_2$

If you are familiar with linear maps, here is a a possible proof. Define $T:M_n(F)\to F^n$ by sending a matrix to the vector containing the sums of the elements of each row. This is clearly a surjective linear map. Let $N=\text{Ker}(T)$. Then by the rank nullity theorem we have $\dim(N)=n^2-n$. Note that $N$ is the collection of matrices where the sum of elements in each row is $0$, so in particular $N\subseteq S_n$.
Now restrict $T$ to $S_n$, so we have a linear map $S_n\to F^n$. The kernel is still the same subspace $N$, and the image now has dimension $1$. Again, by rank-nullity it follows that $\dim(S_n)=n^2-n+1$.

I´m sorry but I think I´m getting lost in the translation (I´m not a native english speaker). What do you mean by "sending a matrix to the vector containing the sums of the elements in each row"? What does it mean to send a matrix to a vector? I´m familiar only with linear transformations and with the rank-nulity theorem in linear transformations.

@gnzlama Linear map and linear transformation are the same thing. I mean, for a matrix $A$ we define $T(A)$ to be the vector $(b_1,...,b_n)\in F^n$ where $b_1$ is the sum of elements of $A$ in the first row, $b_2$ is the sum of elements in the second row, and so on. If $n=2$ and we take the matrix from your example, it will be sent to the vector $(3,3)$.

You can get a specific basis by taking $A_{pq}$ for $p=1,\dots.n, q=1,\dots,n-1$ defined so that $$(A_{pq})_{ij}=\begin{cases}-1&i=p,j=n\\1&i=p,j=q\\0\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then let $B$ be the matrix where $(B)_{in}=1$ for all $i,$ and all other entries are $0.$
Show these are linearly independent and ever element of $S_n$ can be written as a linear combination of these matrices.
If $A=(a_{ij})\in S_n,$ you get:
$$A=cB+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_{ij}A_{ij},$$ where $c$ is the common row sum of $A.$
So, for $n=2,$ the basis looks like: $$A_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\\ 
A_{21}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&-1\end{pmatrix},\\ 
B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&0\end{pmatrix}=3B+A_{11}+3A_{12}.$$

Let $\mathbf B$ be a $n\times n$ lower triangular matrix with the first column the ones vector $\mathbf 1$,  the second column $\mathbf e_2$ the second standard basis vector, the third column $\mathbf e_3$ the third standard basis vector, and so on.  Then for $M \in S_n$ you have $M\mathbf B = \mathbf B A$ where $\mathbf a_1 = \lambda \mathbf e_1$.
Using conjugation consider $\mathbf B^{-1}S_n \mathbf B$ which has a basis given by $E_{i,j} =\mathbf e_i\mathbf e_j^T$ for $2\leq i,j\leq n$ and $E_{1,j}=\mathbf e_1\mathbf e_j^T$ for $1\leq j \leq n$, i.e. $n^2-n+1$ linearly independent elements.  You can confirm that for any $A$ written as a linear combination of these basis vectors
$M\mathbf 1 =M\mathbf B\mathbf e_1=\mathbf B A\mathbf e_1 = \alpha\cdot\mathbf B\mathbf e_1 = \alpha \cdot \mathbf 1$ as required for $M\in S_n$.

This is kind of like @Mark's solution, as it is based on the rank-nullity theorem, but I think it's a bit more straightforward.
Let $M_n(F)$ be the vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices over your field $F$. It has dimension $n^2$.
Define the $n$ linear functions $s_i : M_n(F) \rightarrow F$, $i = 1 ... n$, as $s_i$ is the sum of the $i$-th row of a matrix. These are linear.
Then define $T: M_n(F) \rightarrow F^{n-1}$ as
$$T(m) = (s_1(m) - s_2(m), s_2(m) - s_3(m), ...., s_{n-1}(m) - s_n(m))$$
i.e. take the differences of adjacent rows' sums.
$T$ is linear, and its kernel is your $S_n$. To show that it is surjective, consider the matrices
$$m_i = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&...&0&0\\
1&0&0&...&0&0\\
1&0&0&...&0&0\\
.......\\
1&0&0&...&0&0\\
0&0&0&...&0&0\\
0&0&0&...&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix},\\ 
$$
where the only non-zero entries are the first column of the first $i$ rows. It's easy to see that each $m_i$ gets mapped to the $i$-th standard basis vector in $F^{n-1}$, so $T$ is onto.
So $$
\begin{align}
\dim(S_N) &= \operatorname{nullity}(T) \\
&= \dim(M_n) - \operatorname{rank}(T) \\
&= \dim(M_n) - \dim(F^{n-1}) \\
&= n^2 - (n-1)
\end{align}
$$

A previous item asked for the basis of $S_2$ (which is pretty easy to find), not for the basis of $S_n$.

BTW, even though I think this is the simplest way to answer the question, it still feels like 1.5 points out of 20 doesn't seem like enough.

Yeah I also think the same, when I get my exam back I will post the solution proposed by the teachers.
